# The old log files didn't get removed when using logback RollingFileAppender

Tags: log4j, logback

My logback.xml file as following, and I set MaxHistory=1 in order to delete old log files and only keep the log for one day. But I found the old files didn't get removed. I still could see them as:`app.log.2019-02-11 app.log.2019-02-12`

```
<configuration>
    <property name="APP_NAME" value="logbacktest-logs" />
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="/tmp/${APP_NAME}" />
    <property name="ENCODER_PATTERN" value="%d %C.%method:%L _ %msg%n"/>
    <contextName>${APP_NAME}</contextName>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${ENCODER_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender> 
    <appender name="APP_APPEND" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>1</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${ENCODER_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="APP_APPEND" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a part of my log

> 12:11:32,358 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.

which means that say your application is not up during that time, then it doesn't get a chance to delete it

I had faced a same issue when I had set the maxHistory to 5, it deleted 5 log files sometimes but when my application died it could not delete the logs because it didn't get a chance to delete.

---

Refering the logback docs, it says you can use this:

```
<cleanHistoryOnStart> true </cleanHistoryOnStart>
```

If set to true, archive removal will be executed on appender start up. By default this property is set to false.

Archive removal is normally performed during roll over. However, some applications may not live long enough for roll over to be triggered. It follows that for such short-lived applications archive removal may never get a chance to execute. By setting cleanHistoryOnStart to true, archive removal is performed at appender start up.

---

Modify your piece of logback-spring.xml to:

```
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: Unfortunetely it does not remove logs that does not match current pattent. For example if you pattern `${LOG_HOME}/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}` and current time is `app.log.2021-12-12` it will not remove file like `app.log.2021-10-12` because it's another month. It isn't problem if you start again your app in the same month you stopped it. But if you based on `every minute` history like `app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}` it can't remove old files

Comment: @Stanislau: What is the workaround for that situation then? Did you implement your own mechanism in your application to delete old files?

Comment: @S.Doe In result i just created a cron job that removes all these logs every night. I don't like this solution but these logs were needed for a very short time after the emergency itself. That's why this approach worked for me. If you decide to do something like this too, you can look at `logrotate` in linux.

Comment: My application now iterates the loggers and appenders, casts them to their expected type, reads the log file pattern and the maxHistory value and deletes every surplus log file that matches that pattern (replace "%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" by "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" and "%i" by "[0-9]{1,2}" to get the filename regexp). Prototypically it works. But I think that your `logrotate` is a much better approach.